# change regular user's password with root access

Tags: ubuntu, password

I have Ubuntu installed on a Raspberry pi. I have a normal user `pi`, but I forgot the password. However, I do have root access.

How would I change pi's password using root?

Comment: How did you manage to install Ubuntu on the pi?

Comment: I did it long time ago. I remember: 1st, download the image and burn it into SD card. 2nd, plug in everything and power on then follow the configuration. 3rd, there is no 3rd.

Comment: But what version? It is my understanding that Ubuntu changed long ago so that it no longer works on pi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do :

```
passwd username
```

in your case `passwd pi`

Answer (score -1):

Just open a terminal and type following command:

```
sudo passwd username
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It will ask you for passwords